# Adding HTML tags to axes labels using D3.JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, d3.js

I'm working on simple horizontal bar chart using vue and d3. I wanna customize my axis labels along vertical axis. Now my code where I specify what to put in every label is looking like this:

```
let yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(this.yScale)
  .tickSize(0)
  .tickPadding(4)
  .tickFormat((d, i) => { return this.data[i].country + " " + this.data[i].value })
```

I'd like my labels to look this way:

| country | value |
| --- | --- |
| Country1 | **10.2** |
| Country2 | **200.3** |
| Country2 | **3000.4** |

i.e. country must be aligned left, while value must be right. Besides value must be in bold. The problem is though that it seems as if .tickFormat doesn't accept any html tags

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of styling the axis labels:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)

// Create the scale
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])         // This is what is written on the Axis: from 0 to 100
    .range([100, 800]);       // This is where the axis is placed: from 100px to 800px

// Draw the axis
svg
  .append("g")
  .classed('x-axis', true)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")      // This controls the vertical position of the Axis
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  
svg.select('.x-axis')
  .selectAll('text')
  .style('fill', 'red')
  .style('font-size', '32px')
  .attr('y', 20)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: It's not a problem to customize the whole label, but what to do if I want to make it from two values and customize them separately? For instance I'd like to have as labels something like "Name **Surname**". These two values go from different fields. I wanna align them differently and, lets say, change surname's color or make it bold or whatever

Comment: I think you need 2 parallel axes instead of one (one on the left and one on the right)...